# Can't we sort a "Node module element"?

Tags: entities, nodes

I'm creating a new content type named "Portfolio".

**Image 1:** I put a name to the "Title field label": *Project Name*

[image: Content Type Edit]

**Image 2:** That thing works as a 'Node module element' in Fields

[image: Content Type Manage Fields]

**Image 3:** I can't get the Field to sort it below the Project Image

[image: Content Type Manage Display]

I even can't get this 'Node module element' from Views (using Views module). The sorting problem is specific to "Teasers" in the portfolio page:

[image: Teaser view]

I just want the Project Title to sort a bit so that I can place the title just after the Project Image. [I'm familiar with WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22728/mayeenul-islam), but a newbie in Drupal.

Comment: After an answer: I got something that I missed: **About Image 3**, I'm afraid, I missed to say that, in both the "Default" and "Teaser" tab, the title is missing.

Comment: Did you try the Display Suite module?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to go about.

1) Use views. In views the Field to add is Content : Title. (Even if you change the name of the title field it is still title. It is just changing the label on the form.)

2) You can install [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) Module. Once you install this module you would get additional fields once you select a layout in the layouts section.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files.

3) The third method is to work with the node.tpl.php you have a node object. Since you are using teaser the title would be available in a field. All the other fields can be accessed from the node object.

Answer (score 1):

In image 3, there is another separate tab for editing the order and display of teasers for your content types.

If your content isn't displaying properly in views as a teaser, you can change the format options in your view to show:Fields instead of show:Content , this will then allow you to add specific fields from your content type, and add custom CSS classes to all of your fields for extra formatting in CSS.

Comment: I'm afraid, I missed to say that, in both the "Default" and "Teaser" tab, the title is missing.

Comment: Yes that is correct, in the manage display tab for a content type, you cannot change the order of the title with other fields. 

But if you are only worried about displaying the title below an image while in a view, use fields instead of content:teaser. Then you can set the title field to appear below the image field.

Comment: The [Title Module](https://drupal.org/project/title) might be worth looking into, you can replace the default title with a standard field API, which may allow it to appear on the manage display page.